# Django: Correct select_related in Class Based View

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-class-based-views, django-select-related

Hi Stackoverflow people,

I am experiencing a strange issue with a select_related query in Django. I have installed the [django-cities app](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities), which lists geo information for a large number of cities.
In my project model, I have created a foreignkey to the city element to store the location in my **models.py**.

```
from cities.models import City 
class Project(models.Model): 
   ...
   city = models.ForeignKey(City, blank = True, null = True)
```

Due to the large number of possible cities, I have created a query in my **class based view** which selects the related city field when creating a Project object.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from project.models import Project
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    queryset = Project.objects.select_related('city__country', 'city__region').all()
    template_name = 'solution/solution_create_form.html'
```

However, when I request the ProjectCreate class, **Django still pulls an endless number of foreignkeys from the database**. The logger is showing an unlimited number of the following requests.

> ...
>   DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "cities_region"."id", "cities_region"."name",
>   "cities_region"."slug", "cities_region"."name_std",
>   "cities_region"."code", "cities_region"."country_id" FROM
>   "cities_region" WHERE "cities_region"."id" = 3861887 ; args=(3861887,)
>   DEBUG (0.000) SELECT "cities_country"."id", "cities_country"."name",
>   "cities_country"."slug", "cities_country"."code",
>   "cities_country"."population", "cities_country"."continent",
>   "cities_country"."tld" FROM "cities_country" WHERE
>   "cities_country"."id" = 3865483 ; args=(3865483,) D
>   ...

**How can I force the select related method when I execute the ProjectCreate class?**

Thank you for your help and suggestions!

Comment: show the debug info (SQL) for your Project.objects... query

Comment: Interestingly when I execute `from django.db import connection
    print "Query %s" % connection.queries`, the query is empty. Is there a better way to display the query? Django-toolbar does not work since the site is not fully loaded when the sql requests go wild.

Comment: there is a different way.  Find base.py for your database's driver. On my system, for example, Postgres's base.py is located at </usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py>.  Then find method execute() inside of class CursorWrapper.  Add a new line at the start of the method that print method's arguments: query and args.

Comment: Hm, i get a similar result. Before the sql request goes wild, only one other model is requested. Results: `SELECT postgis_lib_version()
None
SELECT "product_subcategory"."id", "product_subcategory"."category", "product_subcategory"."name", "product_subcategory"."long_name", "product_subcategory"."slug" FROM "product_subcategory"
()
SELECT "cities_city"."id", "cities_city"."name", "cities_city"."slug", "cities_city"."name_std", "cities_city"."location", "cities_city"."population", "cities_city"."region_id", "cities_city"."subregion_id", "cities_city"."country_id" FROM "cities_city"
()
`

Comment: are you by any chance populating the create form's dropdowns with city/region names?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, yes, I the form includes a drop down menu for the foreignkeys in the Project model. Would I have to change anything in the form creation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15541/discussion-between-dmitry-beransky-and-neurix)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any testing, have you tried overriding the `get_queryset` method instead of using the `queryset` attribute? At least you will be more flexible with exception catching and other techniques.